# Sum values in a range of dates with a timezone in it

Tags: date, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a long list of dates with this format:

2019-11-28 10:12:48 -0800

The problem is that the formula I use to sum values in a range of dates do not recognize the cell as a Date. I have to manually delte the -0800 but I have a very long list.

There is any way to format the cells as a date or automatically get rid of the -0800 everytime I import a file using a function?

Comment: If all the values have the same time zone offset, then you don't need to convert to date, since the date value is sortable as a string, and hence also easy to filter. E.g. to select rows for Nov 2019, you can limit using the Google Sheets equivalent of `date >= '2019-11-01' and date < '2019-12-01'`

Comment: Hello Arkshija, may I ask how are you loading these dates? What do you mean by "import a file using a function"? Many Thanks.

Comment: I mean: import the file then execute a script to delete " -0800" of all cells in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to remove every occurrence of `-0800`. This will result in valid dates in your Sheets document.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getDataRange().createTextFinder(" -0800").replaceAllWith("");
}
```

The function uses the `TextFinder` class of Google Apps Script. You may learn more about it and the methods used with it in the following link:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,LEFT(A2:A, 19)*1))
```

[image: 0]

and then just sum it:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,LEFT(A2:A, 19)*1)))
```